# Deploying .NET Core console app as web job not picking up connection string from my config.json

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application, config, azure-webjobs

I have a .NET Core app that i have deployed as a web job, the web job deploys successfully but its not performing any task .. i think it has failed to get connection string from config.json .

.Net Core console app does not comes up with a config file by default so I added one manually and used the following code to read its configuration:

```
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        string directory = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName;
        var builder2 = builder.SetBasePath(directory);
        var builder3 = builder2.AddJsonFile("config.json", true, true);
        _configuration = builder3.Build();

                var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<UserContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("ROSCAConnection"));
            UserContext userContext = new UserContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
```

This works fine on my machine . When I am publishing the .NET Core app its not picking up my config.json file to my publish output .

Here is my config.json file:

```
{
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "ROSCAConnection": "Data Source=***.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=***;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=***;Password=***"
},
"Ripple": {
    "baseURL": "https://s.altnet.rippletest.net:51234",
    "account": "***",
    "secret": "***"
},
"Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "Debug": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Warning"
        }
    },
    "Console": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Warning"
        }
    }
}
```

}

How can I publish this .NET Core console app so that it reads my config.json?

Checking app service editor in azure confirms that config.json does exist

[image]

Comment: `i think it has failed to get connection string frommy config.json` How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: @mjwills i have added image in question ... azure app service editor does confirm that config.json exists .. still web job is not performing its task

Comment: will  Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName; to get config.json work in azure ?

Answer (score 1):

I have test it work, you could refer to the following steps:

1.The `appsettings.json` files `Copy to Output Directory` property should also be set to `Copy if newer` so that **the application is able to access it when published**.
[image]

2.The settings are injected in the main method rather than in the startup method as with web apps but the code is essentially the same. And I use the `appsetting.json` you provided.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
    IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();
    Console.WriteLine("hello");
    Console.WriteLine(configuration.GetConnectionString("ROSCAConnection"));
}
```

3.To resolve `SetBasePath` add a dependency to [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions/) package.
 To resolve `AddJsonFile` add dependency to [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/) package.

4.The webjobs output.
[image]

Comment: Does it make a difference if my config file is named as config.json and not appsettings.json? @JoyeCai

Comment: Actually no different. You need to  ensure the file format is json file and you load this config.json through AddJsonFile. And set the json file property to `copy if newer`. Then it will work fine.

Comment: Hi! Similarly, instead of reading from *.json file, can the `Console` app read the settings defined in Azure App Service's Configuration area?